# convert java functions/method into json object

Tags: java, json

I am building a code summarization algorithm of java methods for which I am trying to build a data set in json file  for training which will look like as follow

java code

```
public void sum(int a,int b){
/*printing the sum of two number*/
System.out.println(a+b);
}
```

JSON file

```
{"code":"public void sum(int a,int b){System.out.println(a+b);}","comment":"printing the sum of two number"}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a community to ask questions and get answers. Please ask a specific question about what problem you have. Also it helps understanding if you post what you have already tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] on how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to write good questions. Your post does not contain an actual question or problem. Also include what you have already done and tried to resolve your question/problem.

Comment: Hi, can you please give more information about what you need, for example: in what language do you need it? Do you need a method that takes a string and returns another string? What is expected when the comment is in //comment format ? Why you need this? etc ..

Comment: There is https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser that can parse Java code. You can study what it can do here https://javaparser.org/presentations/ Be warned that this require some studying and I estimate 20+ hours of work.